# MySQL group by field received with regex

Tags: mysql, regex

From initinal table with a transaction id and transaction sum I need to receive total sums grouped by ids.

The twist is that ids may or may not have a '_rebate' suffix appended to them.

I basically need to ignore it and I can remove it with regex, but then GROUP BY stops working.

That is,
query

```
SELECT contract, REGEXP_SUBSTR(alias_id, '.+?(?=_rebate|$)') as alias_id, sum
FROM yt_reportLIMIT 10
```

returns

```
+-----------+----------------------------------+-------+
| contract  | alias_id                         | sum   |
+-----------+----------------------------------+-------+
| 187453/19 | 758ad57482d621f9b54d67f07b543f46 |  70.8 |
| 187453/19 | 3df373604d0b3f38aca283083468efd5 | 146.4 |
| 187453/19 | 3c6caf755f4e16c798c262ed06a735b3 |  70.8 |
| 187453/19 | 197358f0e522224f9a4e0b24ec265cfc | 139.2 |
| 187453/19 | 0815b324b5e81a199a984442f4d42bc8 |  93.6 |
| 187453/19 | 9e5203f585d622b0a95fc31c2e1a19be | 153.6 |
| 187453/19 | d1e1bbd7302233deac6e18107cac541f |  87.6 |
| 187453/19 | dd92fae2fc9c1fc7b208821f2f913724 | 127.2 |
| 187453/19 | b250e741e4e118fe8289e37f4bfd8523 | 148.8 |
| 187453/19 | 7bf53c61ca61162cb6f1406992acfdff |    96 |
+-----------+----------------------------------+-------+
```

but

```
SELECT te.contract, te.alias_id, ROUND(SUM(te.sum),2) as b_sum 
FROM 
(SELECT contract, REGEXP_SUBSTR(alias_id, '.+?(?=_rebate|$)') as alias_id, sum 
FROM yt_report LIMIT 10) as te
GROUP BY te.alias_id, te.contract LIMIT 10
```

returns

```
+-----------+----------+---------+
| contract  | alias_id | b_sum   |
+-----------+----------+---------+
| 187453/19 |          | 1134.00 |
+-----------+----------+---------+
```

There are no NULL ids in the table. Looks like querying a regex processed field from subquery does not work.

How can this be solved?

Comment: Just FYI: if the column with IDs contains just IDs and only some entries contain `_rebate`, you might as well use `REPLACE(alias_id, '_rebate', '')` instead of `REGEXP_SUBSTR`

Answer (score 1):

You want to group by replaced string, using `te.alias_id` will group by original value, And using `alias_id` will still group by original value as column names preceeds column alias.

So,

- Use another column alias and use it in GROUP BY clause
- or use the same replace expression in GROUP BY clause
- or use column number syntax:

```
SELECT contract
     , REGEXP_SUBSTR(alias_id, '.+?(?=_rebate|$)') as alias_id
     , round(sum(sum),2) sum
FROM yt_report
GROUP BY contract, 2
```